# How rename files .h .cpp in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

How rename source files in QtCreator? I have changed name of class but I don't see option to change files it containing. I'm using 2.7.0 version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using qmake, renaming is easy. Find your files in "Projects" left panel and choose "Rename" in the context menu. Qt Creator will automatically edit `.pro` file replacing filenames.

This option doesn't work with cmake projects. If you're using cmake, you need to rename files outside of Qt Creator. May be you then need to adjust your `CMakeLists.txt` file to include new filenames in the project.

Comment: Note this only works for qmake-based projects. In case you are using CMake, you'll need to rename them outside of Qt Creator.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it. But this method sadly haven't changed `#include ` declarations

Comment: Yes, you need to edit them manually or use project-level find and replace.

Comment: This has always annoyed me. How can QtCreator not change the includes automatically, as well as renaming the .cpp at the same time at the .h... seriously I can see no other real-life scenario, and QtCreator has all the information to do this.

Comment: welcome to everyone visiting in august 2021 (Qt Creator 4.15.2) where this issue is still not resolved....