# Qt Creator: Cannot rename file

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

Any ideas why `Rename...` is disabled when a right-click on a file in the project view? This is a CMake project:

[image]

This is Qt Creator 4.5.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I suspect this kind of re-factoring not working for CMake projects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185199/how-rename-files-h-cpp-in-qtcreator